# How to provide a score value to an image based on pattern information in it?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I saw a few image processing and analysis related questions on this forum and thought I could try this forum for my question. I have a say 30 two-dimensional arrays (to make things simple, although I have a very big data set) which form 30 individual images. Many of these images have similar base structure, but differ in intensities for different pixels. Due to this intensity variation amongst pixels, some images have a prominent pattern (say a larger area with localised intense pixels or high intensity pixels classifying an edge). Some images, also just contain single high intensity pixels randomly distributed without any prominent feature (so basically noise). I am now trying to build an algorithm, which can give a specific score to an image based on different factors like area fraction of high intensity pixels, mean standard deviation, so that I can find out the image with the most prominent pattern (in order words rank them). But these factors depend on a common factor i.e. a user defined threshold, which becomes different for every image. Any inputs on how I can achieve this ranking or a image score in an automated manner (without the use of a threshold)? I initially used Matlab to perform all the processing and area fraction calculations, but now I am using R do the same thing.

Can some amount of machine learning/ random forest stuff help me here? I am not sure. Some inputs would be very valuable.

P.S. If this not the right forum to post, any suggestions on where I can get good advise?

Comment: Didn't understand the part about the "user defined threshold". Could you give more details?

Comment: @FrankPuffer Basically what I did was. I first converted the image to grayscale and generated a histogram of the image. Based on this histogram, I could see an select a percent of gray level above a certain threshold (so basically select all the high intensity pixels, above a certain cut-off). And, then calculate the area fraction of the pixels. But, this cut-off is different for individual images. I am looking for some inputs where I don't have to use such a cut-off instead the algorithm depends on some other factors related to the image.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me suggest a change in terminology: What you denote as *feature* is usually called *pattern* in image prcessing, while what you call *factor* is usually called *feature*.

I think that the main weakness of the features you are using (mean, standard deviation) is that they are only based on the statistics of single pixels (1st order statistics) without considering correlations (neighborhood relations of pixels). If you take a highly stuctured image and shuffle the pixels randomly, you will still have the same 1st order statistics.

There are many ways to take these correlations into account. A simple, efficient and therefore popular method is to apply some filters on the image first (high-pass, low-pass etc.) and then get the 1st order statistics of the resulting image. Other methods are based on Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).

Of course machine learning is also an option here. You could try convolutional neural networks for example, but I would try the simple filtering stuff first.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my terminology usage. I really need to get to know a lot in this field. You are right about the first order statistics. I had tried shuffling the pixels randomly and had this issue even when no specific pattern was present in the image. I will read about the filters and FFT and try to apply it. Maybe I am able to generate a more confident score based on these. Thank you for your suggestions.